# Using basic auth with the apiDiscovery feature in Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am using the **apiDiscovery-1.0** feature in **Liberty** in order to expose the **Swagger UI** for my REST APIs.  However, my REST APIs are secured using **Basic Auth** and the **Authorize** button is not being displayed in the UI exposed by the apiDiscovery feature in Liberty.  Is this supported with the apiDiscovery feature?

The version of Liberty that I am using is as follows:

product = WebSphere Application Server 17.0.0.2 (wlp-1.0.17.cl170220170523-1818)

Comment: Are you using a pre-generated document or annotations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using annotations (JAXRS + Swagger v2), please note that you can only reference security definitions from within your annotated code - to actually declare them you will have to use a Swagger v2 stub document (inside META-INF/stub).

Check this [sample](https://github.com/microservices-api/java-rest-user/tree/master/swagger-sample-application/src/main).

In there we declare the security definition in the [stub](https://github.com/microservices-api/java-rest-user/blob/master/swagger-sample-application/src/main/webapp/META-INF/stub/swagger.yaml) and then reference it from the [annotation](https://github.com/microservices-api/java-rest-user/blob/master/swagger-sample-application/src/main/java/microservices/api/user/jaxrs/ProfileResource.jav).

This is due to a limitation in the Swagger v2 annotation library that doesn't allow for security declarations from within annotations.  This is something we're working to fix for OpenAPI v3.